# Can you see my routes and config with sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt, laravel-sanctum

Using https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum , I'm try create API application.
Generating token is ok.
But when I try to restrict my endpoint to authorized users with middleware, any check permission didn't work, endpoint is accessible for all.
In controller I tested with debug auth('sanctum')->check() - and I became true for valid token and false else.

My routes/api.php

```
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);

    Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'services/{service}',
        'where'  => [
            'service' => implode('|', array_column(ServiceEnum::cases(), 'name'))
        ]],
        function () {
            Route::get('accounts/{account}/balance', [AccountController::class, 'getBalance']);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my fail.
I recreate a project with new fresh laravel (something was broken with installing laravel passport) and then solve a problem with empty auth user in constructor of controller:

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = auth()->user();

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```